# hightchart bug in safari with render svg width

Tags: javascript, ios, json, highcharts

I have this bug only in safari browser. The diagram is smaller in size than my parent div element. Who can help?

[image: safari screenshot]

I fixed this bug. You need to add these styles in chart: spacingBottom: 0, spacingLeft: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0

Comment: Can you create a live example of the issue or paste the code which allows to reproduce it?

Comment: I fixed this bug. You need to add these styles in chart: spacingBottom: 0, spacingLeft: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0